# Configure host base Postfix and send emails using a container

Tags: email, docker, postfix, smtp

I have installed and configured the  `nano /etc/postfix/main.cf` file for postfix in the host server and when I try to send it from the host server `echo "Test Postfix Gmail SMTP Relay" | mail -s "Postfix Gmail SMTP Relay Message" example@mail.com` it's running fine from the host machine. But when I enter the same command from the bash terminal of the container, I get this error `bash: mail: command not found`.

Here is the configuration inside `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated
defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = demo.example.host
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.example.host, , localhost
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
mynetworks = 172.17.0.2 172.17.0.3 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128                                                                                                                                    mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = 172.17.0.1
inet_protocols = all
# Enables SASL authentication for postfix
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
# Disallow methods that allow anonymous authentication
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
# Location of sasl_passwd we saved
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
# Enable STARTTLS encryption for SMTP
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
# Location of CA certificates for TLS
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

So, I am using ubuntu as a host machine, and a simple docker container that sends the email. I want to be able to send the email from the docker's container terminal using the installation of SMTP server or postfix in the host machine.

Comment: Did you find a solution? We probably have to install like `mailutils`, but how to continue then?

Comment: No. haven't yet.

Comment: @membersound any solution at hand?

Comment: Not enough info. What container image are you running? What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: @JivanPal, I have tried to edit the question

Comment: Thanks, but it would still help to know what container you are specifically running. You must be using a `docker run` command or `docker-compose.yml` file to create the container in the first place; please provide it.